# How do I check if a tag is closed in an html file using a stack with java?

Tags: java

I have an assignment that asks us to check the validity of tags within an html file.
I am using a stack based on generics to support multiple data types. I read with the buffered reader the data from the file in lines. I push into the stack the tags that contain "<" and do not contain "

```
    String str = null;
    StringStackImpl<String> stack = new StringStackImpl<>(); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    while((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] line = str.split("\\s") ;
        for(String word : line) {
            if(word.contains("<")&&!word.contains("</")){
                stack.push(word);
            }
            if(word.startsWith("</")) {
                stack.push(word);
            }
    } 
    stack.printStack(System.out);
```

this is the input I use :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the result i am getting

```
</html>
</body>
<body>
<html>
<!DOCTYPE
```

while

Comment: And what is the input you're looking for? Because you are using a stack that works in LIFO (Last In First Out)

Comment: What is the expected input and output?

Comment: I am using the stack, when the algorithm meets an opening tag it should add it in the stack and if its a closing tag it should remove the top of the stack. at the end of the execution the stack should be empty if all the tags are closed or contain the unused tags.

Comment: Why is there a second push instead of a pop if you want to remove it when found?

Comment: Wallkan, damn I feel stupid, I got stuck and I didnt notice. thanks bud. the program works fine!

Comment: I think whoever gave you this assignment really underestimates the real complexity of HTML.

Comment: Our professor said that he wants a basic program that can just see if the file is valid or not. Its one of the 3 things he wants us to do with data structures.

Comment: Not all elements require a closing tag. For example: img, input, hr, area, link, br, meta, base, col, embed, keygen, param, source, track, wbr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you encounter a closing tag you need to get the current top element of the stack. Then you check if it equals the encountered closing tag. If yes, then remove the top element from the stack.

```
String str = null;
String topItem = null;
StringStackImpl<String> stack = new StringStackImpl<>(); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
while((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] line = str.split("\\s") ;
    for(String word : line) {
        if(word.contains("<")&&!word.contains("</")){
            stack.push(word);
        }
        if(word.startsWith("</")&& !stack.empty()) {
            topItem = stack.peek().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
            if(topItem.equals(word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", ""))){
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
} 
stack.printStack(System.out);
```

Comment: I really wish parsing HTML was this easy!

Comment: Hmm I really like the design and I will implement some parts of it, however, if the file is formed like this : 
<html>
<body>
</p>
</body>
</html> 
(With no opening tag <p> and just a closing one it doesnt work. If the stack is empty and it meets a closing tag it should abort mission and return right?

Comment: If it encounters a closing tag without the appropriate opening tag nothing happens in the current code. I'll leave that up to you to implement. Futhermore if it encounters a closing tag on an empty stack it doesn't do anything because of the `!stack.empty()`. If you want some logic there, feel free to add it, or shoot me a message if you can't figure it out

Comment: @m0skit0 I do agree, this code is missing alot of 'edge cases' but it's a good start for his assignment I think